# Build process taking forever with kotlin on intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to run kotlin on IntelliJ.However, the build process is taking forever and nothing appears as an output. I spent several days without solving the problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAJcH.png)

Comment: you can check intellij logs. try creating new project, clear all intellij specific files

Comment: Do you have antivirus/firewall? Please try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan.